# Wait for subscribe result inside a function that return an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Consider the following function

```
Go(publicRoute: boolean, token: string) {
    let rtrn = {} as aaResult;

    if (publicRoute) {
        rtrn.Authenticated = true;
    }
    else {
        if (token != "" || this.userService.Get() != null) {
            if (this.userService.Get() != null) {
                rtrn.Authenticated = true;
            }
            else {
                this._authorize(token).subscribe(res => {
                    console.log("internal subscribe");
                    console.log(res);
                    this.userService.Set(new User(res));                      
                    if (this.userService.Get() != null) {
                        rtrn.Authenticated = true;
                        rtrn.User = this.userService.Get()
                    }
                    else
                        this._authenticate();
                }
                    ,
                    error => {
                        this._authenticate();
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        else {
            this._authenticate();
        }
    }

    return (Observable.of(rtrn));
}
```

If the first `if` is `true` the return data is correct. If the `if` is `false` the return data is `{}` because the function doesn't wait for the results of `this._authorize`. How can I make the function wait for the result of internal observable?

This is how the whole thing gets called, just in case:

`this.AA.Go(this.publicRoute, this.internalToken).subscribe(res => { console.log(res) })`

EDIT

Adding code for the `authorize` function turned into observable

```
private  _authorize(token: string, options?: any): Promise<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.config.aa.autherizationUrl + "?token=" + token, {
        headers: this.Utils.SetRequestAppOptions(options === undefined ? {} : options),
    }).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: is `UserService.Get()` returning an `Observable`?

Comment: No, it's just simple variable holder service.

Comment: can you please add content of `_authenticate()`?

Comment: I was planning to rewrite and add the code as an answer but anyway, my take would be place your `return` statement in the `subscribe` block. Then place couple more `return` statements in the function or use `toPromise` so you can async/await it without subscribing ;)

Comment: I don't get it. If you want to return an observable then why do you subscribe?

Comment: @abetteroliver I want to return an onbservable that has been built using the information from the result of the `_authorize` function. Hence why I need to make the parent function wait until `_authorize` completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider, since observables are asynchronous, changing the `this._authorize` return type to a promise. So then you can do `await this._authorize`.

The await specifically waits until the function is completely executed, before moving on. Await only works on promises, so you need to change the return type.

If the function is an observable. You can use `.toPromise()` to make it a promise in an easy way.

**EDIT**

Asuming that you have the method returning an observable, this should work. On promises, the result is stored on a variable, so you can't subscribe to it.

This shoud work:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

async function GoAsync(publicRoute: boolean, token: string) {
  let rtrn = {} as aaResult;

  if (publicRoute) {
      rtrn.Authenticated = true;
  }
  else {
      if (token != "" || this.userService.Get() != null) {
          if (this.userService.Get() != null) {
              rtrn.Authenticated = true;
          }
          else {
              try {
                 let res = await this._authorize(token); //wait for the response
                  console.log("internal subscribe");
                  console.log(res);
                  this.userService.Set(new User(res));
                  if (this.userService.Get() != null) {
                      rtrn.Authenticated = true
                      rtrn.User = this.userService.Get()
                  }
              }
              // avoid else's and catch, using finally.
              catch {
                  // error handle here
              }
          }
      }
      // allways perform this action, as stated in your code
      this._authenticate();
  }
  return (rtrn);
}

function Go(publicRoute: boolean, token: string) {
    return from(GoAsync(publicRoute,token))
}
```

Comment: Could provide code? I get `can not find name await` and `subscribe doesn't exist for type Promise<User>` errors. I did `toPromise` the `_authorize` function

Comment: @americanslon  I have updated the response and added some code. Hope it works :)

Comment: Still get `can not find name await` on `await`. I have edited the main question to show the `authorize` function

Comment: It seems that this technique made `Go` function return a promise of an observable  and not an observable so subscribing to the `Go` function no longer works.

Comment: Try with this, now the go async funtion returns a Promise<aaReslt> and then it just makes it an Observable using the rxjs form function